# Is this the right way to think about relative probability?

Tags: probability

I have two groups of people, let's call them bowlers. One group uses a heavy ball and the other group uses a light ball.

Everyone rolls just once. Of the people who use the light ball, 34% roll a gutterball. Of the people who use the dark ball, 39% roll a gutterball.

Is it fair to say that people who use the dark ball are 13% more likely to roll a gutterball?

Comment: "Likely" in what sense?

Comment: There is an association where people who roll the dark ball get a gutterball 13% more often.

Comment: This is very vague. What kind of "association"? You mean hypothesis testing? Or is it a question about terminology?

Comment: Ratios of probabilities sometimes make sense and are useful. The reason why they give us pause here is that your choice of describing the chances in terms of "roll a gutterball" is arbitrary: it would be equally justifiable to give the chances of "not rolling a gutterball." The problem is that those chances are 61% and 66%, which is only 8% more likely.  Which is right: 13% or 8%?  This discrepancy usually leads people to express chances in a way where *how you characterize* an event doesn't influence *how you express a difference in chances.* That suggests using odds rather than probability.

Comment: I think @whuber comment is excellent. It is also fair to say that people using the dark ball roll a gutterball $5\%$ more often. Here, the increase is in "percentage points", a different meaning entirely but that's the point. It is worth noting that this statement is less ambiguous in the sense that it does not suffer from the same discrepancy as whuber points out above.

Comment: "One group uses a ***heavy*** ball and the other group uses a ***light*** ball. [...]
Of the people who use the ***dark*** ball"  -- so wait, by the end there are three different kinds of ball?